# How can I sort XML elements by their attributes?

Tags: xml, jq

How can I sort this XML?

1. first by alphabetical element: `module` before `property`.
2. then by the alphabetical name attribute: `<module name="ClassTypeParameterName"/>` before `<module name="PackageName"/>`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Checkstyle//DTD Checkstyle Configuration 1.3//EN" "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">
<module name="Checker">
  <property name="severity" value="error"/>
  <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"/>
  <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile"/>
  <module name="FileTabCharacter"/>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="PackageName"/>
    <module name="ClassTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="InterfaceTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="MethodTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="LambdaParameterName"/>
    <module name="PatternVariableName"/>
    <module name="RecordComponentName"/>
    <module name="RecordTypeParameterName"/>
    <module name="TypeName">
      <property name="format" value="^[A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
    </module>
    <module name="AvoidDoubleBraceInitialization"/>
    <module name="AvoidNoArgumentSuperConstructorCall"/>
    <module name="OneTopLevelClass"/>
    <module name="OuterTypeFilename"/>
  </module>
</module>
```

I'd like to use `xq` as used here: [Sorting an XML file in UNIX with a Bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659230/sorting-an-xml-file-in-unix-with-a-bash-script)

Comment: I added the [tag:jq] tag to the question as `xq` is a wrapper around `jq`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```bash
xq -x -S 'walk(if type == "array" then sort_by(."@name") else . end)' file
```

This uses `-S` (or `--sort-keys`) to sort the keys (XML tags) using their names so that the `module` keys come before the `property` keys.

It then uses the recursive `walk()` function to apply `sort_by()` to each array, sorting the elements of each array based on the value of the `name` attribute (written `."@name"`).

This `walk()` usage is almost identical to [an example in the `jq` manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#walk(f)).

This would produce the following output:

```xml
<module name="Checker">
  <module name="FileTabCharacter"></module>
  <module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile"></module>
  <module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="AvoidDoubleBraceInitialization"></module>
    <module name="AvoidNoArgumentSuperConstructorCall"></module>
    <module name="ClassTypeParameterName"></module>
    <module name="InterfaceTypeParameterName"></module>
    <module name="LambdaParameterName"></module>
    <module name="MethodTypeParameterName"></module>
    <module name="OneTopLevelClass"></module>
    <module name="OuterTypeFilename"></module>
    <module name="PackageName"></module>
    <module name="PatternVariableName"></module>
    <module name="RecordComponentName"></module>
    <module name="RecordTypeParameterName"></module>
    <module name="TypeName">
      <property name="format" value="^[A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$"></property>
    </module>
  </module>
  <property name="fileExtensions" value="java"></property>
  <property name="severity" value="error"></property>
</module>
```

Note that `xq` writes out the end tags explicitly, even for empty nodes. If you want to fix that (so that `<tag attr="..."></tag>` is changed to `<tag attr="..."/>`), pass the result through `xmlstarlet fo` or `xmlstarlet format`.

---

As a reference, the JSON document that the original XML document is translated into (with no sorting whatsoever) and to which the `jq` expression is applied is the equivalent of the following:

```json
{
   "module": {
      "@name": "Checker",
      "module": [
         { "@name": "NewlineAtEndOfFile" },
         { "@name": "FileTabCharacter" },
         {
            "@name": "TreeWalker",
            "module": [
               { "@name": "PackageName" },
               { "@name": "ClassTypeParameterName" },
               { "@name": "InterfaceTypeParameterName" },
               { "@name": "MethodTypeParameterName" },
               { "@name": "LambdaParameterName" },
               { "@name": "PatternVariableName" },
               { "@name": "RecordComponentName" },
               { "@name": "RecordTypeParameterName" },
               {
                  "@name": "TypeName",
                  "property": { "@name": "format", "@value": "^[A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
               },
               { "@name": "AvoidDoubleBraceInitialization" },
               { "@name": "AvoidNoArgumentSuperConstructorCall" },
               { "@name": "OneTopLevelClass" },
               { "@name": "OuterTypeFilename" }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "property": [
         { "@name": "severity", "@value": "error" },
         { "@name": "fileExtensions", "@value": "java" }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I didn't include in the example, but how would you preserve xml declaration, doctype, cdata etc?

Comment: @caduceus Use `xq` with its `--xml-dtd` option. I don't know about CDATA sections (I don't think it can be made to preserve these as they are).

Comment: not working xq 3.1.0

Comment: @caduceus `xq --xml-dtd -x ... file` preserves the `<?xml ...?>` tag. This works for me using `xq` release 3.1.0. What is it exactly that does not work for you?

Comment: the doctype is gone

Comment: @caduceus Yeah, `xq` does not keep track of that at all, to my knowledge. At least with the CDATA section, it keeps them, albeit while transforming them into XML-encoded strings.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue to the OP (with the added problem of the xml containing customer data, ruling out online tools) and first went down the route of using `xq`. I had some decent success specifically with this script here as a starting point: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659245/367314.

In the end however I found a nice plugin for `vscode` which allows you to sort blocks of code allowing you to configure depth too.  Thought I'd post here in case it helps anyone else.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=1nVitr0.blocksort

[image: demo of the blocksort plugin]

Should you want to sort only certain blocks in a file, you can select those blocks in the UI and just sort the ones you're interested in or smartly sort the entire document.

Not a good solution if you're trying to automate things, but is good for one-offs.